# Utilizando Highchart se sopreponen lineas en un diagrama de red (Networkgraph)

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

Tengo el siguiente grafico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quisiera que no se sobrepongan los links ni los label links cuando indico dos conexiones con el mismo punto de inicio y fin como se ven del punto A al punto L
Mi codigo en javascript es el siguiente

> Highcharts.chart('container', {
> chart: {
> type: 'networkgraph',
> height: '100%'
> },
>
> ```
> /*
> events: {
>   load() {
>     let series = this.series[0];
>     series.data.forEach(function(point, i) {
>       if (point.color) {
>           series.nodes[i + 1].color = point.color;
>       }
>     })
>   }
> },*/
>
> title: {
>     text: 'Test Integrations'
> },
> subtitle: {
>     text: 'Network Chart Integrations'
> },
> plotOptions: {
>     networkgraph: {
>         keys: ['from', 'to'],
>         layoutAlgorithm: {
>             enableSimulation: true,
>             friction: -0.9,
>             linkLength: 100,
>         }
>     }
> },
> series: [{
> dataLabels: {             enabled: true,          allowOverlap: true,
>   linkFormat: '{point.label}'
> },
> id: 'Integrations_Network_Graph',
>     data: [
>     {from: 'A', to: 'B', "label": "I1"},
>     {from: 'A', to: 'C', "label": "I2", color: "red"},
>     {from: 'A', to: 'E', "label": "I3"},
>     {from: 'A', to: 'F', "label": "I4"},
>     {from: 'A', to: 'G', "label": "I5"},
>     {from: 'A', to: 'H', "label": "I6"},
>     {from: 'A', to: 'I', "label": "I7"},
>     {from: 'A', to: 'J', "label": ""},
>     {from: 'A', to: 'K', "label": "I8"},
>     {from: 'A', to: 'L', "label": "I9"},
>     {from: 'A', to: 'L', "label": "I10"},
>     {from: 'A', to: 'M', "label": "I11"},
>     {from: 'A', to: 'N', "label": "I12", 
>     color: "red"},
>     {from: 'A', to: 'O', "label": "I3"},
>     ]
> }] })
> ```